# dont understand why categories arent collapsing

Tags: php, html, database

So I am super confused, I am using a template and I have a side menu that shows categories, when you press on the category a drop down menu with corresponding categories related to id's from initial category. When I press the category it is not giving me the desired results. When the href is clicked it gives me the results of the initial categories and not the categories corresponding with the href id that was clicked. Not sure what im doing wrong?
[current results with code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlfuf.png)

```
<div class="catagories-menu">
  <ul id="menu-content2" class="menu-content collapse show">
    <?
     $database = new DB();
     $query = "select * from category where cat_SubCat IS NULL";//
     $rows = $database->get_results($query);
     foreach ($rows as $row)//foreach database result
     {                              
        echo"<li data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#$row[cat_Name]' class='collapsed' >
                <a href='#' id='$row[cat_ID]'>" . $row[cat_Name] . "</a>
                <ul class='sub-menu collapse' id='$row[cat_Name]'>
                    <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>";
                    $database = new DB();//creating an object from the class
                    $query2 = "select * from category where cat_SubCat=" .$row[cat_ID]."";//
                    $subs = $database->get_results($query2);
                    foreach ($subs as $sub)//foreach database result
                    {
                      echo"<li><a href='prodDetail.php?cat_ID=".$sub[cat_ID]."&cat_SubCat=".$sub[cat_SubCat]."' class='list-group-item'>" . $sub[cat_Name] . "</a></li>";
                    }
            echo"</ul>
             </li>";
     }
     ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Im looking for the null categories to print first and the ones associated to the nulls to print beneath
[desired reults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD3nK.png)
updated code from Khan's entry and replaced the $subs = $database->get_results($query);
 
  with
$subs = $database->get_results($query2);
it worked partially. Code is not allowing drop down for first two categories but other categories are displaying really confused

Answer (score 0):

In sub you are using query, and not query2

```
foreach ($rows as $row)//foreach database result
     {                              
        echo"<li data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#$row[cat_Name]' class='collapsed' >
                <a href='#' id='$row[cat_ID]'>" . $row[cat_Name] . "</a>
                <ul class='sub-menu collapse' id='$row[cat_Name]'>
                    <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>";
                    $database2 = new DB();//creating an object from the class
                    $query2 = "select * from category where cat_SubCat=" .$row[cat_ID]."";//
                    $subs = $database2->get_results($query2);
                    foreach ($subs as $sub)//foreach database result
                    {
                      echo"<li><a href='prodDetail.php?cat_ID=".$sub[cat_ID]."&cat_SubCat=".$sub[cat_SubCat]."' class='list-group-item'>" . $sub[cat_Name] . "</a></li>";
                    }
            echo"</ul>
             </li>";
     }
```

Comment: Thank You Khan for the that. I still am having trouble because the first two categories are not printing the subcategories for security/outdoors and lamps/lights but the subcategories are printing for households and beyond

Comment: That is a different issue. Try to just echo out everything... without the UL and LI. Comment out current echoes and write new one... just echo name and ID to verify you are getting all items from database.

Comment: everything is printing out correctly when I strip the ul's, li's, and href's away

Comment: I believe it is because you are assigning category name as ID....  id='$row[cat_Name]'  but both of your first categories have special characters which is invalid ID. Use cat_id instead of cat_Name.

Comment: went through and replaced the the cat_Name with cat_ID in the <li data-target = #$row[cat_ID]> as well as in the <ul id =  $row[cat_ID) but no luck]

Comment: the a tag also has the same id, the cat_id. Use a prefix like nav_1, nav_17 etc. You should be able to view your page source and see all items in the html. it is the nav expand/collapse feature that i snot working.

Comment: not sure i understand <a href='#' id ='$row[cat_ID]'> are saying use something like <a href='#' id ='nav$row[cat_ID]'>

Comment: Yes. Use  <a href='#' id ='nav_$row[cat_ID]'> so that the UL and A tags will both not have the same IDs